# How to make date time picker components are editable in code name one?

Tags: codenameone

Currently we are using date with time picker, We looking the feature on this date time picker when user try to edit and type his/her own Date or Hours or Minutes or AM/PM component.

Is these achieve by using code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR75t.png)name one date time picker component?. please help us or guide us how to achieve this.

Please find the screen shot of the date and time picker.

Answer (score 0):

The picker looks native on the various OS's so this UI won't appear. Furthermore a `Picker` is just a button styled to look like a text field.

You can call the low level show native picker API's in `Display` and bind them to text fields for editing abilities.